# Code First cascade issue

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship, cascade

this is the error I'm getting:
***"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint `FK_dbo.RolePermissions_dbo.Permissions_Permission_ID` on table `RolePermissions` may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors."***

and here are my classes:

```
public class Permission
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PermissionObjectId { get; set; }
    public PermissionObject PermissionObject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ReadWriteId { get; set; }
    public ReadWrite ReadWrite { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

}

public class Category 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID.ToString();
    }
}
```

what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use fluent api for set CascadeOndelete = fasle .

See This Link May Be Help you : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399918/how-to-make-two-relations-between-two-tables/22400417#22400417)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like EF is trying to create a relationship of some sort between Roles and Permissions (many-to-many?), but you also have one-to-many relationships for category-role and category-permission which also have cascade delete enabled.

For foreign key relationships when using non-nullable keys or `[Required]`, (e.g. `CategoryId` in both `Role` and `Permission`), cascade delete is enabled by default.